# MATLAB function error when importing data: At compilation, "data" was determined to be a variable

Tags: matlab

I have a function but I cannot deal with the variable named data when I call the function. If I run the code alone (without calling the function, it works).

Please find the actual code below:

```
function data = returns_ext(input);
clear all
clc

ticker = 'BA';
filename = ['C:\Users\FP\Documents\MatlabCode\P\prices\' ticker 'daily.csv'];

newData1 = importdata(filename);

% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = fieldnames(newData1);

for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end

prices_data = data;
```

ERROR: At compilation, "data" was determined to be a variable and this
 variable is uninitialized.  "data" is also a function name and previous versions of MATLAB would have
 called the function.
 However, MATLAB 7 forbids the use of the same name in the same
 context as both a function and a variable.

```
Error in ==> returns_ext at 17
prices_data = data;
```

Comment: Is `data` a field in `NewData1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `assignin` by eval, since `assignin` assigns either in the caller function calling `returns_ext` or the base workspace. See the simple example below:

```
function test
newData1.prices = 1;
newData1.dates = 2;

variables = {'prices','dates'};
for i = 1:length(variables) 
    temp = newData1.(variables{i});
    eval([variables{i} ' = temp;']);
end

disp(prices)
disp(dates)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still have problems (sorry the code is only a part, don't look at the output). I created two new variables with 'caller' instead of 'base' (and they appear in the workspace), but I still can't access them:
variables = cell(2,1);
variables{1} = 'prices';
variables{2} = 'dates';

for i = 1:length(variables)
    assignin('caller', variables{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end
all_dates_and_prices = zeros((size(prices,1)),2);

ERROR:
??? Undefined function or variable 'prices'.

Error in ==> returns_ext at 24
all_dates_and_prices = zeros((size(prices,1)),2);

Comment: @FrancescoVe Yes, I was a bit wrong. `caller` is not the actual function but the function calling your function, in this case, the function (or workspace) calling returns_ext. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, I'm close to the end! I have no more errors, but instead of prices_data I get a variable called 'ans' (with the correct content) and dates_data is lacking. The code is: 

function [prices_data,dates_data] = returns_ext(ticker);

...

vars = fieldnames(imported_data); % result is {'prices','textdata'}

for i = 1:2
    temp = imported_data.(vars{i});
    eval([vars{i} '= temp;']);
end

prices_data = data;
dates_data = textdata;

Comment: It seems you run your function from within the editor. In this case (without any further settings) only the function is executed but the results not assigned to variables (`ans`) is always the last result from any call. Just you function from Matlab command window with `[prices_data,dates_data] = returns_ext(ticker);`

Answer (score 0):

If the data is available in 'base' workspace then you need to update your code as this:

```
data = eval('base','data;');
prices_data = data;
```